# Should an Android module or library be used to reuse fragments with different resources?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, module, android-library

I have an Android fragment that I want to use in multiple applications. The fragment has number of images that are used as buttons. In each application, I would like to use a different set of resources. For example the images in one application will be different from the images in another, but there will still be a one-to-one correspondence between images that will be the same size.

My understanding is that a module is code and resources, while a normal library is just code. If I build a module, are all of the resources related to the fragment internal to the module, or can images be different for different applications using the module? Can a library approach work, assuming that all of the resource files requested by the fragment are available within the application? This seems to be very poor encapsulation, but I don't see how to avoid this if resources are included in the module.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, You want to use the fragment from the library project and want to change the images specific to the app.

If this is the case, make that library fragment as `abstact` and force the child fragments to implement methods to initialise the image views. This should be like

`protected ImageView profilePicIV;`

`// Abstract Methods`
  `protected abstract initialiseProfilePic();`
  `protected abstract initialisePic1();`
  `protected abstract initialisePic2();`

Then extend the Fragment in the Library and implement the methods.

`@override<br/>
    protected abstract initialiseProfilePic()
    {
      profilePicIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
    }`

Call this method from constructor of Library fragment.

Regards,
Sha